# SQL request doesn't work with 2 conditions using LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm trying to make a double condition request like this :

```
SELECT id, statut, nom, nom_deux, email, email_deux, adresse, adresse_deux, ville, codepostal, role_clients
FROM sys_clients
INNER JOIN sys_clients_roles
ON statut = id_clients
WHERE sys_clients.statut = 1 
AND sys_clients.nom LIKE 'a%'
ORDER BY sys_clients.nom ASC;
```

When I use only

```
WHERE sys_clients.statut = 1
```

The sql request is correct and I have the result but when I add

```
AND sys_clients.nom LIKE 'a%'
```

It's not working and I have a HTTP error 500.
I want to avec all 'nom' begining by an 'a' letter.

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: maybe you have uppercase initial letters for the names. So, consider using `lower(sys_clients.nom) LIKE 'a%'`

Comment: How will you get a `HTTP error 500` from a SQL statement ??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

could be a problem is  related  to use of (single) quote be sure you have double quote around your sql code

```
$sql ="SELECT id
      , statut
      , nom
      , nom_deux
      , email
      , email_deux
      , adresse
      , adresse_deux
      , ville
      , codepostal
      , role_clients
  FROM sys_clients
  INNER JOIN sys_clients_roles ON statut = id_clients
  WHERE sys_clients.statut = 1 
     AND sys_clients.nom LIKE  'a%'
  ORDER BY sys_clients.nom ASC;"
```